# How to Install Sikuli in Robot Framework?

Tags: user-interface, automation, robotframework, sikuli

I have an existing robot framework projects but now i want to integrate sikuli to my robot framework. I find all the information in the web in integrating Sikuli a bit hard or lets say, i cant understand it fairly well. I am not a very technical person thus, may I ask for you help on installing one. Thanks!

Comment: Check this link - https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Seen this one also. http://www.8bitavenue.com/2012/04/sikuli-selenium-robot-framework-tutorial/ but i still wasnt able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pip install

```
pip install robotframework-SikuliLibrary
```